# Question regarding a proof of the Combinatorial Nullstellensatz

Tags: combinatorics

N. Vishnoi has provided a slick proof of the combinatorial nullsetellensatz at http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nvishno/site/publications_files/valon.pdf . The part that I am not understanding is towards the end where he says: "It is easy to see, as in the expansion of h, each term must be of the type $qg_i$." I am not sure why each term in $h$'s expansion is of that form. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5t3ou53bbitvlw/AProofOfThePuncturedCombinatorialNullstellensatz.pdf?dl=0 Here I have written down a proof of the Punctured Combinatorial Nullstellensatz, which is a generalization of the Alon's Nullstellensatz, in the spirit of Vishnoi's proof. What Vishnoi deems as "easy to see" in his proof was not easy to see really.

Comment: This is great! Thanks caffinemachine.